# In Dialogflow how to stop bot Telegram if the bot was deleted before it's stopped in Dialogflow?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I've got Dialogflow bot integrated with Telegram. I decided to change bot in Telegram. Created a new one, deleted the previous one in Telegram. But haven't stopped it in Dialogflow before these operations. Now whenever I try to stop it, Dialogflow reports error and doesn't stop it.
The error says:

```
com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: {"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"}
```

Also it's not possible to create a new agent, bcs Dialogflow doesn't allow to use the same GCP project. And I cannot delete existing one.

How can I stop it to change API Token now? Or delete the existing agent?